# Facing error when dockerising streamlit app: NotImplementedError: docx2pdf is not implemented for linux as it requires Microsoft Word to be installed

Tags: python, docker, streamlit

I built a streamlit app and am trying to dockerise it. In my streamlit app, I import the docx2pdf python library. I built the docker image and tried to open the app on my local host. However, I am facing the above error.

Also, I am using Docker Desktop and built the image with docker on my command prompt terminal (Windows).

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code for docker-compose or streamlit, it's impossible to know how you're actually creating the container. Read: [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also a good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you everything you need to know. So does the [docx2pdf pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/):

> Convert `docx` to `pdf` on Windows or macOS directly using Microsoft Word (must be installed).

MS Word needs to be installed for this library to work. And if you are containerising it, then the container needs to have MS Word installed, or the associated libraries which `docx2pdf` uses. So you need to use Windows containers, and not Linux containers - Docker Desktop allows both on Windows. As well as installing whatever OS-environment is needed for MS Word to run.

Alternatively, use a library which doesn't require MS Word. This isn't the site for library recommendations.